# Swift: Set Variables for TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView and my tableViewCell has a `isLiked` variable and a `likeButton`. I would like to set my `likeButton's` tintColor accordingly to the state of `isLiked`. The way I have done it is that I retrieve a list of posts from Firebase that the user has liked, and then pass it into the tableView. If the postID tallies with the list, I would like to set the isLiked variable to true.

However, despite setting this logic in cellForRow, the isLiked variable in tableViewCell is not set accordingly. How can I get it set accordingly? My code as follows:

```
// in TableViewController
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        let post: FIRDataSnapshot = self.posts[indexPath.row]
        let postValues = post.value as! [String: AnyObject]
        let postID = postValues["postID"] as! String

        for likedPosts in usersLikedPostsList {
            if likedPosts == postID {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    cell.isLiked = true
                }
            } else {
                cell.isLiked = false
            }
        }

        return cell
    }
// in TableViewCell
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var isLiked: Bool?

    @IBOutlet weak var likeButton: UIButton!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        print(isLiked)
        if let _ = isLiked {
            likeButton.tintColor = .red
        } else {
            likeButton.tintColor = .darkGray
        }

    }
}
```

From the print statement, `isLiked` variable is nil when the table is loaded. I have attempted with `self.tableView.reloadData()` but it does not set it accordingly as well.

Note that I would like to manipulate `isLiked` state in TableViewCell because I wanna add code to toggle its state within TableViewCell, so that users can like and unlike the post, and perform the updates to Firebase accordingly as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cell `awakeFromNib()` method is executed only once, when the first time the cell is instanciated from storyboard or Nib file, so you need to update your cell every time this value `isLiked` change, try with his code

```
    // in TableViewCell
    class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var isLiked: Bool = false{
        didSet{
            likeButton.tintColor = .darkGray
            if(isLiked)
            {
                likeButton.tintColor = .red
            }
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var likeButton: UIButton!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

```
let post: FIRDataSnapshot = self.posts[indexPath.row]
let postValues = post.value as! [String: AnyObject]
let postID = postValues["postID"] as! String
```

Try your above code in view did load and make postID as global variable.
and print to see if it returns anything or use .count to check it.

If it has count more than 1.Then try to use postID in method :cellForRowAt

Secondly, tableview reload will work only if numberOfRowsInSection have different value from last time.

Check whether this method is called or not when you reload table.